# How can I show daily grid lines in HighStock? Currently seems buggy

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am using Highstock to create a GANTT style workflow, but I'm using the X-Range Highcharts plugin to allow for start and end dates on the X-axis. I am trying to get grid lines to display on every day, so I set the following on the X-axis:

```
tickInterval: 24 * 36e5
```

However, the grid lines only appear on every week. I've searched all over but can't seem to find a solution specific to this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrClever88/LeL28nqr/5/) showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts prevents from rendering too many ticks on the chart. Maybe the current logic is a bit harsh, but you can always use `xAxis.tickPositioner`, take a look: 
            tickPositioner: function() {
                console.log(this.tickPositions);

```
            var tp = this.tickPositions,
                first = tp[0],
                last = tp[tp.length - 1],
                ticks = [],
                interval = 24 * 36e5;

            while (first <= last) {
                ticks.push(first);
                first += interval;
            }

            return ticks;    
        },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LeL28nqr/6/

For a better readability, I suggest to change `labels.step` option - for example set to every 7th day: http://jsfiddle.net/LeL28nqr/7/

Comment: Pawel, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I've read a lot of your helpful comments on Highcharts. I do though need to keep all of the labels, but I want the navigator to represent a shorter timescale by default (e.g. only show 10 days). Do you know if there's a way to do this without using rangeSelector? (This seems to give me other issues entirely!)

Comment: You can control the view by `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`?

Comment: Pawel, of course I can, sorry that was a stupid question! I've been so bogged down with this other issue I think I just need to take a step back! Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Sorry @Paweł Fus - I've spotted another issue and I wondered if you could shed any light. In the series 'Holiday' the data are only showing where y=0 (i.e. only the first person is showing any holiday) - shown in [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrClever88/LeL28nqr/11/) starting on line 386. Any idea why this might be? If not I can post as another question. All the other series seem fine.

Comment: I see errors regarding unsorted data in the console. When sorting data, it works fine: `data: [ ... ].sort(function(a, b){ return a.x - b.x; })` (#584 line).